# How to transfer files from remote server to my local desktop using jump host (? gateway server?)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I may be using wrong terminology because I am new to this, so let me clarify in layman's terms. So, I have to access the files on my work desktop, from my laptop at home. I have been provided with a username, an IP Address and the password to what I believe is called the "gateway". I know the IP of my work desktop. I first connect to the gateway server using the provided details and the ssh command. Then I can again use the ssh command to login to my work desktop. I can thus access all my data, run jobs, etc. However, for analyzing the generated data, I need to get all the output files to my local PC, i.e., my laptop. I tried doing scp to the gateway and then planned on doing sftp get command from the gateway to my laptop. However, when I do the scp, I get the error

```
ssh: connect to host 2**.**.**.*** port 22: Connection refused
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your gateway A and your work computer B. You have two possibilities how to transfer files from B to your home computer

1. scp data from B to A and then scp from A to your computer, something like

```
ssh A
scp B:data .
exit
scp A:data .
```

2. Much better option, but requires setup is to use ssh proxy
   in your `~/.ssh/config` on home computer create something like this

```
host B
  User <username on B>
  HostName <IP of B>
  IdentityFile <path to your id_rsa on on A>
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  ProxyCommand ssh user@A "nc -q 0 %h %p"
```

if you setup second option, you can do `ssh B` directly. And `scp B:data .` which is your goal.

Comment: So the first option is what I tried, but scp B:data gives the 'connection refused' error as written in my question details.

Comment: can you show full examples of both working ssh and failing scp?

Comment: Okay I'm sorry. I finally figured it out. I was doing the scp from my remote desktop to my gateway server, wherein lies my mistake. When I did scp command from the gateway, it worked. I guess it is kinda a unidirectional thing. Maybe I will read more into this to understand how gateway servers work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. 
Just to react to what you wrote last - there is nothing special about that "gateway" server. Actually, don't call it gateway, those are called jump hosts, gateway is a network term.
Jump hosts are used a lot. It can be in a situation like yours when you login from home to jumphost and then from it you jump to actual host you want to reach. Otherwise there would need to be a direct connection from your home to your work machine which would be a security nightmare.